# Memory variables vs storage variables in Vyper

Tags: vyper

Is there a way to specify if a variable is memory or storage like we do in solidity ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Vyper experts might be able to confirm, but I don't think memory and storage *pointers* are implemented in Vyper.

(For a run-down on what I mean by pointers, see this article by Rob on Solidity pointers: https://blog.b9lab.com/storage-pointers-in-solidity-7dcfaa536089)

If really you're just interested in the initial declaration of variables, then I think this is all implicit in a given variable's scoping; meaning that any variable declared inside a function is a memory variable, and any variable at the global scope is a storage variable.

(See the scoping section of the [docs](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scoping-and-declarations.html#scoping-and-declarations), though they're not really much help in this case... )